# Python script to find path by file name

Tags: python, file, indexing

Looking for a script to replace the "where" command in cmd. I know I can write a script to run "where" from python.
I am looking for something more efficient such as a python library to search for files by name any suggestions?
To sum it looking for the best way to find a file path by name.

Comment: @Dimitris Manos ofc thats the obvious answer I just don't know if doing that is faster than something like os.Popen('where /r ./ exmaple.exe')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

def find_files(filename, search_path):
   result = []

# Wlaking top-down from the root
   for root, dir, files in os.walk(search_path):
      if filename in files:
         result.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
   return result
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I have no problem with the code but I'm looking for something faster if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

def find_files(filename, search_path):
   result = []

   for root, dir, files in os.walk(search_path):
      if filename in files:
         result.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
   return result

print(find_files("smpl.htm","D:"))
```

Here we need to give drive path to find out the files location.